# MS Access 2013 ShortcutMenu to filter in runtime

Tags: ms-access

I tried to create a ShortcutMenu for my Report, so that i can filter the rpeort while in runtime mode.

I added following code to a module:

```
Sub CreateSimpleShortcutMenu()
Dim newMenu As CommandBarControl
Dim cmb As CommandBar
On Error Resume Next 'If menu with same name exists delete
CommandBars("ShowDataShortcutMenu").Delete

CommandBars("ShowDataShortcutMenu").Delete

Set cmb = CommandBars.Add("ShowDataShortcutMenu", msoBarPopup, False, False)
With cmb
    .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 21, , , True).BeginGroup = True     'Cut
    .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 19, , , True    'Copy
    .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 22, , , True    'Paste
    Set newMenu = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 4016, , , True)
    newMenu.BeginGroup = True
    newMenu.Caption = "&Sort A to Z"
    newMenu.OnAction = "=SortAZ()"
    Set newMenu = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 4017, , , True)

    newMenu.Caption = "S&ort Z to A"
    newMenu.OnAction = "=SortZA()"
    .Controls.Add msoControlButton, 605, , , True   'Remove Filter/Sort
    Set newMenu = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    newMenu.Caption = "Te&xt Filters"


    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10077, , , True    'Filter equals xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10078, , , True    'Filter not equal to xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10079, , , True    'Filter beings with xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 12696, , , True    'Filter does not beings with xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10080, , , True    'Filter contains xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10081, , , True    'Filter does not contains xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10082, , , True    'Filter ends with xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 10083, , , True    'Filter ends with xx
    newMenu.Controls.Add msoControlButton, 12697, , , True    'Filter does not ends with xx

End With

Set cmb = Nothing
Set newMenu = Nothing

End Sub

Function SortAZ()
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SortUp")
End Function

Function SortZA()
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SortDown")
End Function
```

In the Reports.OnLoad i call

```
CreateSimpleShortCutMenu
```

I would also need to set shortcut menu into the propertys but it's not showing up when i go to the reports propertys -> other -> shortcut menu

Can someone help me?

Edit: Also i get this Error Message: 
**User-defined Type Not Defined" Error Message**

Answer (score 0):

The code was working as intended. 
What was missing is a reference to Object Library. 
I added the Reference and it worked.

Even works in runtime.